# How to sync all html files using gulp browsersync?

Tags: gruntjs, gulp

I have a directory structure like this...

```
--app
 -css
  custom.css
 -sass
  custom.scss
 -pages
  about.html
  home.html
--gulpfile.js
--node_modules
--package.json
```

my gulp file is

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function () {
    gulp.watch('app/sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/pages/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
})

gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
    browserSync.init({           
        server: {
            baseDir: "app",
            index: "pages/home.html"
        },
        })
})
```

when i run the watch task i am redirected to localhost:3000 that opens my home.html page. and my browser sync works fine.

but when i right click on about.html file and view it in browser in visual studio, browser sync doesn't work in about.html page. and this page opens as localhost:56060/app/pages/about.html in the browser.

How can i make browser sync working in all html files inside pages directory?

or what should be the url address of the browser to access about.html file?

Comment: You are using two different ports here. Try to set browsersync port to 56060 too.

Comment: i have tried to change the port to 56060 using

gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        port: 56060 ,
        server: {
            baseDir: "app",
            index: "pages/home.html"
        },
        })
})...

but after that when i run watch task i am redirected to http://localhost:56061

Comment: did you try proxy: 'localhost:56060' instead of port?

Comment: i have tried that,too. Its not working yet, It shows page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, try in browser "chrome" past url adress , ofcourse when in Your CMD console command **gulp watch** is activated

```
http://localhost:3000/pages/about.html
```

Remember if you activated browserSync in your case it is started in folder **app** , this your localhost:3000 server , something like localhost:56060 it is not your page.

In your html files don't forget in css link add "/" before css folder.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css">
```

If you have still issue , try this code in gulp task watch :

```
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function () {
    gulp.watch('app/sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
    // gulp.watch('app/pages/*.html', browserSync.reload); // Comment this line 
    gulp.watch("app/**/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload); // Try this line
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
})

gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
    browserSync.init({           
        server: {
            baseDir: "app",
            index: "pages/home.html"
        },
        })
})
```

Regards :)

Comment: yes this way i can access the about.html in browser, but its not connected to browser sync i.e. whenever i make a change it's not reflected directly in the about page. I have to refresh that page every time to see the changes while browserSync seems to be working fine for home.html.